# Spring MVC: strange @ResponseBody behavior

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring-mvc

Hello
I've got hierarchy `B extends A`. `A` has property `valueA`, B has property `valueB`. Spring MVC example method

`public @ResponseBody A justTesting() {

         return new B();

    }`

JSON answer will be `{"valueB":"valueB","valueA":"valueA"}`, but I expected `{"valueA":"valueA"}` because my Interface returns A
How can I fix return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition doesn't matter here. The object that is returned is serialized.

You can do either of the following:

- use `BeanUtils.copyProperties(..)` to copy properties from the `B` instance to a new `A` instance, specifically created to be returned.
- return `new A()`
- mark `valueB` in `B` as `@JsonIgnore`